# dojo checkbox objects and the ArcGIS JS api

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis

I have another problem that maybe someone can help me fix.  I'm trying to follow example code [HERE](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/widget_legendvisible.html).

I'm trying to incorporate the code into a larger script I've got -- everything works ok except that the checkboxes don't appear.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
require([
"esri/map", 
"esri/dijit/HomeButton",
"esri/layers/FeatureLayer", 
"esri/dijit/Legend", 
"dojo/_base/array", 
"dojo/parser", 
"dijit/layout/BorderContainer", 
"dijit/layout/ContentPane", 
"dijit/layout/AccordionContainer", 
"dojo/domReady!"
], function(Map, HomeButton, FeatureLayer, Legend, arrayUtils, parser){

parser.parse();

var map = new Map("map", {
    basemap: "streets",
    center: [-87.702733, 41.998508],
    zoom: 15
});

var home = new HomeButton({
            map: map
        }, "HomeButton");
        home.startup();

var junctions = new FeatureLayer("http://54.243.188.50:6080/arcgis/rest/services/TYLIN/Streetlights_Pilot/MapServer/0", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields: ["*"]
});

 var power = new FeatureLayer("http://54.243.188.50:6080/arcgis/rest/services/TYLIN/Streetlights_Pilot/MapServer/1", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields: ["*"]
});

var cityNorth = new FeatureLayer("http://54.243.188.50:6080/arcgis/rest/services/TYLIN/Streetlights_Pilot/MapServer/2", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields: ["*"]
});

var citySouth = new FeatureLayer("http://54.243.188.50:6080/arcgis/rest/services/TYLIN/Streetlights_Pilot/MapServer/3", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields: ["*"]
});

var controllers = new FeatureLayer("http://54.243.188.50:6080/arcgis/rest/services/TYLIN/Streetlights_Pilot/MapServer/4", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields: ["*"]
});

var circuits = new FeatureLayer("http://54.243.188.50:6080/arcgis/rest/services/TYLIN/Streetlights_Pilot/MapServer/6", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields: ["*"]
});

var elec = new FeatureLayer("http://54.243.188.50:6080/arcgis/rest/services/TYLIN/Streetlights_Pilot/MapServer/8", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields: ["*"]
});

var cityBoundary = new FeatureLayer("http://54.243.188.50:6080/arcgis/rest/services/TYLIN/Streetlights_Pilot/MapServer/9", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields: ["*"]
});

var curbs = new FeatureLayer("http://54.243.188.50:6080/arcgis/rest/services/TYLIN/Streetlights_Pilot/MapServer/10", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields: ["*"]
});


map.on("layers-add-result", function (evt) {
    var layerInfo = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function (layer, index) {
      return {layer:layer.layer, title:layer.layer.name};
    });
    if (layerInfo.length > 0) {
      var legendDijit = new Legend({
        map: map,
        layerInfos: layerInfo
      }, "legendDiv");
      legendDijit.startup();
    }
});

map.on("layers-add-result", function(evt){
    var layerInfo = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function(layer, index){
        return {
            layer: layer.layer,
            title: layer.layer.name
        };
    });
    dojo.forEach(layerInfo, function(layer){
        var layerName = layer.title;
        var checkBox = new dijit.form.CheckBox({
            name: "checkBox" + layer.layer.id,
            value: layer.layer.id,
            checked: layer.layer.visible,
            onChange: function(evt){
                var clayer = map.getLayer(this.value);
                clayer.setVisibility(!clayer.visible);
                this.checked = clayer.visible;
            }});
        dojo.place(checkBox.domNode, dojo.byID("toggle"), "after");
        var checkLabel = dojo.create('label', {
            'for': checkbox.name,
            innerHTML: layerName
        }, checkBox.domNode, "after");
        dojo.place("<br />", checkLabel, "after");
    });
});


map.addLayers([junctions, power, cityNorth, citySouth, controllers, circuits, elec, cityBoundary, curbs]);

 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding dijit/form/CheckBox to your require statement.